# A non well formed numeric value encountered from XML feed?

Tags: php, xml

I am getting **feeds** from **XML feeder** and when i try to **convert** it's **date values**, i am getting **notice**:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered on line 61

Feeds returns **date** in this **format**:

> 24.06.2015

and time in this format:

> 12:00

I tried to **convert** it like this:

```
$dbdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($match->attributes()->date));
$dbtime = date('h:i', strtotime($match->attributes()->time));
$datetime = date('Y-m-d h:i',$dbdate . ' ' . $dbtime);
```

In **database** it is converted as i want, but i get notice before that.

What i am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

SOLVED, i forget to add strtotime in $datetime :

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime($dbdate . $dbtime));
```